# how to programmatically get new region as Map moves so I can refresh annotations? (swiftui)

Tags: ios, swiftui, mapkit

I have a map with fixed annotations, the annotations change only if I filter the results with a function

I'd like to *recalculate the region as user moves the map* and show the FILTERED results that match that location (get new region coordinates, then call my getListingsFiltered function)

**how can I get the region coordinates when the map changes?** I have seen I can use region.center for the move without zoom and regin.span for zoom in/out) but I couldn't make it work.

I've seen also that other answers change region based on change of results, but in my case it's the contrary, I want to change results based on change of map location.

my map
[image]

desired result (zillow)
[image]

**Map**

```
Map(coordinateRegion: self.$region,annotationItems: model.listingsFZ!) { listing in
                    MapAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: listing.latitude ?? 0, longitude: listing.longitude ?? 0)) {
                        NavigationLink {
                            ListingDetailView(listing: listing)
                          } label: {
                              PlaceAnnotationView(title: listing.priceShort ?? "")
                          }
                    }
                }
                .onDisappear {
                    model.clear()
                }
```

**Function**

```
    func getListingsFiltered(location: String, PriceMin: String, PriceMax: String, Bedrooms: Int) {
        
        var listingsF = [ListingsZillow]() //new array instance of listing
        
        var regionSearch = self.region
        
        var lowestPrice = 0
        var highestPrice = 1000000000
        
        if PriceMin == "Any" {lowestPrice = 0} else {lowestPrice = Int(PriceMin) ?? 0}
        if PriceMax == "Any" {highestPrice = 1000000000} else { highestPrice = Int(PriceMax) ?? 1000000000}
        
        //append the ones that match
        for listing in self.listingsZ! {
            
            //no region selected
            if regionSearch.center.latitude == 0 || regionSearch.center.longitude == 0 {
                if listing.price! >= lowestPrice && listing.price! <= highestPrice {
                     **some code**
                }
            } else {
                //there is a regionselected
                if listing.latitude != nil {
                    
                    let listingRegion = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: listing.latitude, longitude: listing.longitude)
                    
                    if self.checkRegion(location: regionSearch.center, contains: listingRegion, with: 1000){
                        
                        //condition price
                        if listing.price! >= lowestPrice && listing.price! <= highestPrice {
                            //condition bedrooms
                            if listing.bedrooms! >= Bedrooms {
                                //condition location
                                
                                var l = ListingsZillow()
                                l.address = listing.address!
                                
                                l.bedrooms = listing.bedrooms
                                l.bathrooms = listing.bathrooms
                                l.price = listing.price
                                l.yearBuilt = listing.yearBuilt
                                l.longitude = listing.longitude
                                l.latitude = listing.latitude
                                l.homeStatus = listing.homeStatus
                                l.description = listing.description
                                l.livingArea = listing.livingArea
                                l.url = listing.url
                                l.photos = listing.photos
                                l.priceShort = listing.priceShort
                                
                                listingsF.append(l)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            } 
               
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //self.listingsF = listingsF
            self.listingsFZ = listingsF
            self.filters = true
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: You already have it. `region` is a `Binding`. It is constantly being updated.

Comment: So I just use a onChange ($region) then call results function?

Comment: I wouldn't use `.onChanged` as ANY twitch from the user on the map will call the function. You would crash your app. I would make a Combine publisher with a `.debounce` and let that trigger your update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with the `span` in the `region`.

```
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D{
    ///Check if the `coordinate` is within the `MKCoordinateRegion`
    func isWithinRegion(region: MKCoordinateRegion) -> Bool{
        var result = false
        //Get the upper and lower bounds of the latitude and longitude
        //center +/- span/2
        //divide by 2 because the center is half way through
        let latUpper = region.center.latitude + region.span.latitudeDelta/2
        let latLower = region.center.latitude - region.span.latitudeDelta/2
        let lonUpper = region.center.longitude + region.span.longitudeDelta/2
        let lonLower = region.center.longitude - region.span.longitudeDelta/2
        //If the coordinate is within the latitude and the longitude
        if self.latitude >= latLower && self.latitude <= latUpper{
            if self.longitude >= lonLower && self.longitude <= lonUpper{
                //It is within the region
                result = true
            }
        }
        
        return result
    }
}
```

If you add the code above to your project you can use something like

```
listing.coordinate.isWithinRegion(region: regionSearch)
```

in your filter.

The function will return `true` if the coordinate is within the `region`

You can dynamically set the annotations by using a computed variable

```
///Returns the  `visibleAnnotations` that are within the `region`
var visibleAnnotations: [ListingAnnotation]{
    //Your filter code 
    model.listingsZ.filter({
        $0.coordinate.isWithinRegion(region: region)
    })
}
```

Or just hide the listings if the operation is time-consuming

```
NavigationLink{}
    .opacity(listing.coordinate.isWithinRegion(region: vm.region) ? 1 : 0)
    .animation(.easeIn(duration: 1), value: listing.coordinate.isWithinRegion(region: vm.region))
```

Comment: Got it. The thing is I trigger my filter function when the map appears. How can I tell my code the region has changed? Onchange($region) then call filter function?

Comment: You can do it in a computed property. the `region` you have already keeps track of the changing region so it will trigger a view refresh. You haven't provided reproducible code so it is hard to give you an example but you will see a variable above. But if your function is very time consuming you might just what to alter the visibility of the items

Comment: this works great, the only "problem" is that my annotations are usually 600+ if the user zoom out the region, so the app become sluggish rendering so many annotations in the region. I wonder if I could use a condition if span <0.5 then cap listings to 100 (listings.prefix(100)) what do you think?

Comment: That could be an option, just focus on the center annotations. You could also create a formula that groups listings by distance manually or switch to MKMapView and use its grouping. Or you could Aadd additional filters too, I look at the realtor app every once in a while and the annotation images get smaller if you go too far out and it just doesn’t show anything, but it seems natural because the the further your view the smaller the dot. It makes you want to zoom back in.